# WorkManager takes dramatically longer on Samsung device than Pixel

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-workmanager, samsung-galaxy

I'm using WorkManager version `'2.2.0'`.

I'm using a pixel 3 with OS 10, and also a Samsung Tab S4 with Android OS 9. Both devices are in the same wifi, using the same app, performing the same task.
The task is to download a large amount of JSON data from the network, parse it, and save it in the local database.

Both devices are using a single WorkManager that performs a loop of network calls to get the JSON data in pages.

On the pixel, this takes about 2-3 minutes.

On the Samsung Tab S4, this doesn't complete ever because it takes over 10 minutes, and WorkManager resets the Work request at 10 minutes, and the process starts again.

My question is, why on Earth is this process taking so much dramatically longer on the Samsung device than on the Pixel device?

FWIW, both devices have plenty of HDD space available, and have no other app running.

Thanks.

Comment: Add some logging to determine where the time is being spent (network? parsing? database I/O? something else?).

Comment: that's my next step (I think) but when we just run this using a broadcast receiver we dont see this difference of performance per manufacturer, and I keep finding online that WorkManager seems to have different implementations based on the device manufacturer - which sounds awful. So, I wanted to know if anyone knows why its so bad on Samsung

Comment: There's no manufacturer specific code in WorkManager, FWIW.

Comment: ah, thanks @ianhanniballake. i was just saying from what I found online from a couple of hours of research

Comment: WorkManager has workarounds for bugs in some JobScheduler implementation, on different devices/brands, but these are about how the worker are started. Once your Worker is running, it is just about your code and the Android OS. In this particular case it maybe some implementation difference on the filesystem or some native library that is not optimized. My suggestion is to measure where the time is spent on the Samsung device, this will allow to understand what is the root cause of this behavior.

Comment: after further research, it seems like the database I/O tasks are running much slower on Samsung devices than they do on Google Pixel devices and emulators. I'm not quite sure why yet, and it is unclear if the WorkManager code has anything to do with this.

Comment: guys, thanks for the feedback. We've broken our long network + db tasks into multiple workers. However, how are then supposed to keep track of db tasks (including the start/end transaction) when we they have all been started by multiple async rx workers? @ianhanniballake